# Unknown Music Notation for Vocals

Tags: notation, voice

I would to ask what the notation circled in red meant. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess this is the intended range for the exercises. I.e. the first exercise top note is c, so they suggest to transpose it up in half-tone steps by up to a perfect fifth, when that note becomes g, as noted in the circle.

Please note this is a suggestion from the author and you should adjust it to your own voice range.

Comment: For what it's worth, my wife is a vocal teacher and understood the notation in the same way you did. Something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCxmDUl8__U

Comment: That seems the most likely intended meaning.  Though I don't think it's at all clear.  (I think range/ambitus is usually put at the beginning of a piece.)  Some text would have helped.

Comment: Each exercise shows two repetitions, with the second raised by a half step.  I wonder if simply, "etc. ad lib, adjusting for vocal range" would have been better?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a vocal slide? Some vocal coaches use it to smoothen out the break in the mix. Would make sense to try to gently glide across a wide range without breaking as an exercise after doing some other exercises

Comment: While slides are indeed good exercises, I don't think that was intended in this case, as the layout's wrong: the notes are small, too close together, and in incomplete bars.